# MotionLayout: After transition horizontal recyclerview doesn't display the first element

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-motionlayout, android-motionscene

I'm trying to implement a Transition but I have an issue with the first element of the recyclerview. Currently, the transition looks like this:

[image: When the transition ends the first element is not displayed]

When the transition ends the first element in the recyclerview is not displayed, but after I've scrolled.

Currently, I use:

- ConstraintLayout 2.0.0
- RecyclerView 1.1.0

My MotionScene file looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@layout/activity_main_motion_layout_end"
        app:constraintSetStart="@layout/activity_main_motion_layout_start"
        app:layoutDuringTransition="honorRequest"
        app:motionInterpolator="linear">
        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragUp"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top" />
    </Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

The layouts could be find in my repo:

- [activity_main.xml](https://github.com/DevPicon/kotlin-marvel-hero-finder/blob/motion-layout-test/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml)
- [activity_main_motion_layout_start.xml](https://github.com/DevPicon/kotlin-marvel-hero-finder/blob/motion-layout-test/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main_motion_layout_start.xml) file
- [activity_main_motion_layout_end.xml](https://github.com/DevPicon/kotlin-marvel-hero-finder/blob/motion-layout-test/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main_motion_layout_end.xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I've solved this issue by adding the data loading for the recycleview using `MotionLayout.TransitionListener` interface